# Total not updating - Angular JS scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<tbody ng-init="cartArray.total = {}">
    <tr ng-repeat="item in cartArray">
        <td class="cart_product"><a href="#"><img ng-src="images/products/{{item.productImageName}}" alt="Product"></a></td>
        <td class="cart_description">
            <p class="product-name"><a href="#">{{item.prodName}} </a></p>
            <small><a href="#">Color : Red</a></small>
            <small><a href="#">Size : M</a></small>
        </td>
        <td class="availability in-stock"><span class="label">In stock</span></td>
        <td class="price"><span>Rs. {{item.prodAmt}}</span></td>
        <td class="qty"><input ng-model="qty" class="form-control input-sm" type="text"></td>
        <td class="price"><span ng-init='cartArray.total.prodtotAmt = (+cartArray.total.prodAmt*qty) + (+item.prodAmt*qty)'>{{item.prodAmt*qty}}</span></td>
        <td class="action"><a ng-click="removeFromCart(item)"><i class="icon-close"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
        <td colspan="3">Total products (tax incl.)</td>
        <td colspan="2">Rs {{cartArray.total.prodtotAmt}}</td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

With the above code, When I change the value of qty textbox, concerned product's total amount gets changed but however cartArray.total.prodtotAmt is resulting to a incorrect value, can someone help on this?

Comment: you probably want it to have `type="number"` instead of `type="text"`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey It doesn't work :(

Comment: Move this cartArray.total.prodtotAmt = (+cartArray.total.prodAmt*qty) + (+item.prodAmt*qty) to propper function and call it from the control. And do not keep business logic and calculation logic on the UI, make your life painless.

Comment: @Vitalii Actually I don't have the value of qty in array, I'm getting it from input box, I'm not sure how to deal this in controller, thought this would be simple

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you are trying to get total cart amount

**html**

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in cartArray">
    <td class="cart_product"><a href="#"><img ng-src="images/products/{{item.productImageName}}" alt="Product"></a></td>
    <td class="cart_description">
        <p class="product-name"><a href="#">{{item.prodName}} </a></p>
        <small><a href="#">Color : Red</a></small>
        <small><a href="#">Size : M</a></small>
    </td>
    <td class="availability in-stock"><span class="label">In stock</span></td>
    <td class="price"><span>Rs. {{item.prodAmt}}</span></td>
    <td class="qty">
        <input ng-model="item.qty" class="form-control input-sm" type="number">
    </td>
    <td class="price"><span>{{item.prodAmt*qty}}</span></td>
    <td class="action"><a ng-click="removeFromCart(item)"><i class="icon-close"></i></a></td>
</tr>
```

footer

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="3">Total products (tax incl.)</td>
    <td colspan="2">Rs <span ng-bind="ctrl.getTotalCartAmount()"></span></td>
</tr>
```

**js**

```
ctrl.getTotalCartAmount = function(){
    var total = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i<$scope.cartArray.length; i++){
       var item = $scope.cartArray[i];
       total += item.prodAmt*item.qty;
    }

    return total;
}
```

Comment: I was expecting the answer from you, it works like a charm..thank u :)